# JSF2 and PrettyFaces... how does one get the original URL or the query string?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

PrettyFaces is a dead simple URL rewriting engine. All sorts of SEO is possible and it is *really really easy*. I have one small problem though :(

Using pretty faces, I have this rewrite rule:

```
<url-mapping id="blogEntry">
    <pattern value="/blog/#{shortUrl}" />
    <view-id value="/blogEntry.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

So the URL bar looks like:

```
http://host.com/blog/first-post
```

And the rewrite rule maps the request internally to:

```
http://host.com/blogEntry?shortUrl=first-post
```

I'm implementing OpenID, which means I need to give the OpenID provider a return-to URL. However, when I do the following:

```
originalUrl = Faces.getRequest().getRequestURL().toString()
```

I get:

```
http://host.com/blogEntry.jsf
```

getQueryString() returns an empty string

Anyone know of way to either get the purty URL: `http://host.com/blog/first-post` or at minimum the query string `shortUrl=first-post`

Comment: Did you try FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("shortUrl");??

Comment: @RAvi yes, it returns an empty map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use: `PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequestUrl().toURL()` and `PrettyContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequestQueryString().toQueryString()`

Similar forum post:
http://ocpsoft.org/support/topic/how-get-the-original-request-uri-from-jsf