# How to configure url mapping to get all* url request to one jsf page in PrettyFaces / Rewrite

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

1. Can I configure PrettyFaces / Rewrite for mapping all incoming URL request to one page?
2. Then how I can get full URL path after domain name from PrettyFaces / Rewrite? Maybe have some annotation or some like this {URLPATH}? [Looks like this, but maybe have another solutions on this moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916243/jsf2-and-prettyfaces-how-does-one-get-the-original-url-or-the-query-string)

I need: from all requests with:

```
"/../../../*......." or/and "/a/b/c/*/*/*/.." or/and "/{param}/**" or/and "/{param}/{param2}/{param3}/**/**"
```

map to one JSF page.

Something like this:

```
<url-mapping id="pages">
    <pattern value="/**" />
    <view-id value="/pages.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

In Spring MVC I do this like "/україна/452454/45/4774/7744/longpath.html":

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/**"},method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String info(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String remainingPaths = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    return "<H1>Good Work</H1><br/>" + remainingPaths;
}
```

On output I have:

```
<H1>Good Work</H1><br/>/україна/452454/45/4774/7744/longpath.html
```

How I can get same effect from PrettyFaces / Rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) is the solution you are looking for. First, you'll need to upgrade from "PrettyFaces 3.x" to "Rewrite Config PrettyFaces" using the steps outlined here: [PrettyFaces Homepage](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/). This should be a drop-in replacement, requiring no additional configuration on your part.

Once you've upgraded and verified that your application is working normally using the "Rewrite Config Prettyfaces" module, you'll want to create a Rule in a new Rewrite Configuration Provider (follow the steps on the Rewrite Homepage):

```
package com.example;
public class AllPagesToOneViewProvider extends HttpConfigurationProvider
{
   @Override
   public int priority()
   {
     return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public Configuration getConfiguration(final ServletContext context)
   {
     return ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
       .addRule(Join.path("/{all}").to("/pages.xhtml"))
       .where("all").matches(".*");
    }
}
```

NOTE:

> ^^ Make sure to register this Configuration Provider in your META-INF/services (as described in the instructions!)

I've also [added an issue to support the super-wildcard character](https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/issues/105) in the next version of Rewrite, meaning you will be able to use a Join Annotation instead of being required to create a Configuration Provider just for this one rule (however, I think you will find the Configuration API useful.)